# Is it legal to sell a product whose primary function is illegal?

Tags: criminal-law, disclaimers

I saw these stickers for sale [here](http://iparkedinabikelane.bigcartel.com/), and it got me curious about the legality of selling them. Is the seller at risk of being charged as an accessory to vandalism (or some similar crime) ?

[image]

They do have a big disclaimer on their website, but is that really enough to absolve them of any legal wrongdoing ?

> By purchasing and using these stickers, you agree that #IParkedInABikeLane assumes no responsibility or liability due to altercation, injury, damages, legal issues, etc due to individual use of these stickers, and your actions are of your own accord.

But the stickers are clearly being marketed with the intention of placing on someone else's property (vandalism).

> The concept is simple - you see a vehicle parked in a bike lane, you slap a sticker on it. The intention isn’t to cause damage or vandalize (the stickers don’t damage anything anyway) - it’s to get drivers to think twice about what they are doing and perhaps change their actions in the future.

Comment: "But the stickers are clearly being marketed with the intention of placing on someone else's property"  My first thought on seeing the sticker was that you would put it on your own car to proclaim that you didn't care about bikers, but parking in a bike lane might also be illegal, so maybe that distinction is irrelevant.

Comment: In many places, the laws against parking in bike lanes are not enforced. I think that's one of the reasons these stickers emerged. But, my question is about the legality of selling these stickers, not parking in bike lanes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer I received from a lawyer that practices in Alabama:

> The disclaimer may or may not protect the seller. Basically, disclaimers are not ironclad protection. It all depends on the situation. State laws can influence the legality. For example, it is not illegal to sell radar detectors but it is illegal to use them in some states.
>
> Also, most lawyers would not take such a small case, but one could be found. The cost of damage to the car would likely put it in small claims court, which in Alabama, you cannot have a lawyer. Now, if the sticker somehow caused a bigger problem then maybe a lawyer would take the case. Ex. If the sticker was put on the side view mirror, and the driver got in an accident because it was blocked. A lawyer might use that to show someone else is liable for the accident.
>
> Of course, you should not drive with an obstructed side view.mirror, but that might not be against the law in every state.